# In Ruby how can I abort a connection with a RESET?

Tags: ruby, sockets

In any socket API the close() method closes a connection with a FIN. If I want to abort a connection with a RST how can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a normal Ruby TCPSocket, you can turn on SO_LINGER by doing something like this:

```
linger = [1,0].pack('ii')
socket.setsockopt(Socket::SOL_SOCKET, Socket::SO_LINGER, linger)
socket.close
```

Comment: The answer is good,but I found a mistake,see:
the second line should be `sock.setsockopt(Socket::SOL_SOCKET, Socket::SO_LINGER, linger)`

Comment: I've edited the answer to reflect the correction in the first comment - I've tested this and the correction works. Also edited to reflect that the question now asks about Ruby, and not RubyEventMachine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I had some testing to do of behavior when a connection reset was received, so this was perfect :-)